# ElasticSearch - Querying only for particular array elements that are not empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to ES and am having difficulty finding really good references or tutorials on the query dsl.

We have a document type of the example below.  The query I wish to conduct is thus: "Return all the email_package records that have at least one entities record (one record in the 'entities' array)."  And yes I want the complete 'email' record.

Could anyone assist? Also if you could point to a reference or tutorial or cookbook somewhere that addresses question like this, that would be also greatly appreciated.

```
"email_package": {
                    "email": {
                        "date": "2007-02-13T18:24:22-04:00",
                        "subject": "this is the subject",
                        "body": "this is the body"
                    },
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "Louisville": {
                                "City": "South"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Memphis": {
                                "City": "South"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
               }
                // more 'email_package records follow...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your document is a bit problematic, since you seems to be nesting objects and giving them different names. If you are not bound to the current structure, I would have changed the mapping into something that is more manageable, and queries will be straight forward, e.g:

```
"email_package": {
    "email": {
        "body": "this is the body1", 
        "date": "2007-02-13T18:24:22-04:00", 
        "subject": "this is the subject"
    }, 
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "Louisville"
            "City": "South", 
         }, 
        {
            "name": "Memphis"                 
            "City": "South", 
        }
    ]
}
```

Query:

```
{ "filter": {
    "exists": {
        "field": "email_package.entities.name"
    }
 }
```